# Entity Framework mysterious connection string error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I am using this connection string with Entity Framework 5:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="RBSDbContext" connectionString="data source=.;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;initial catalog=RBS; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Adding something this way works:

```
ctx.Categories.Add(new Category {Name="Another" });
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Adding something this way also works:

```
 ctx.Set<Category>.Add(new Category {Name="Another" });
 ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Adding something this way doesnt work:

```
public T Add<T>(T item, bool commit = false) where T : class
{
        var aSet = this.Set<T>();

        aSet.Add(item);

        if (commit)
        {
            SaveChanges();
        }

    return item;
}
```

With the method being called:

```
Repo.Add<Category>(new Category { Name = "Repo" }, true);
```

Giving this error:

```
[ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString.VerifyLocalHostAndFixup(String& host, Boolean     enforceLocalHost, Boolean fixup) +907230
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +4116
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +150
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value) +59
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +4
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +26
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString) +382
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString) +392
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +581
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +31
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +363
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +31
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +34
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +124
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +33
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName) +226
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity) +228
System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity) +72
```

Can anyone help or explain why it works for one and not the other? and why it is complaining about the connection string?

Comment: 'attachdbfilename'  is attribute for connectionstring , and in datasourse: your database server name

Comment: @Niks I have not used that attribute in my connection string.